# Can use simulator 6.1 in Xcode 6.0.1?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

My OSX version is 10.9.5, and I want to use simulator 6.1 in XCode 6.0.1. However, there is no iOS 6.1 Simulator

```
XCode->Preference->Downloads
```

to download, and i move the directory named "iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk" to

```
/Applications/Xcode6.0.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs
```

which doesn't work for me either. Can anyone use simulator 6.1 in Xcode 6.0.1?

Comment: I would not waste time to do such thing, plus, it is easier (and more reasonable!) to update the application for iOS7+ SDK in long term.

Answer (score 2):

Only the iOS 7, 7.1 and 8 simulators are available in Xcode 6.

In order to use the 6.0 version of the simulator you would need to search for and install an older version of Xcode.